# Does .htaccess Rules Increases Load Time?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Does rules in .htaccess file increase load time on server? I am confused. I tried to search about it but results shows benefits of caching, etc. Does redirection of rewritten URLs to index.php helpful or it increases server load time?

Is it better to have a PHP routing library rather than redirection through .htaccess?

Comment: Simple answer is no ... If you had a massive .htaccess file, it may increase server time slightly, but nothing to be worried about. .htaccess has a lot more pros than to be worried about server load time :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, .htaccess rules increase the response time.

But don't worry about a single redirection rule, unless you have to deliver a high performance system.

.htaccess files are read on every request.
If you have a complex directory hierarchie, all .htaccess files are included and parsed (top-down) on each request. A redirection is a new request, so the files are parsed again.

Things to avoid: big files, many files, really complex regexp rules, multiple redirections.

Keep your .htaccess compact, small and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for every rule you use regex and need the FSM-Mashine or the Apache rewrite module to parse the rules. If you have a lot auf rewrite rules its possible that your request will be a bit slower. But the rewrite module is very fast. So normally you will not recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, .htaccess rules directly take actions with server responce. So that's why it will effect on server load time. But It will consume normal time, but you should have to write correct rule in it, then it will not do so ;)